# HTML creating 2 rows with contents in div

Tags: html, css, rows

Fairly new to HTML and coding..
I'm having trouble with a box that needs to display 8 items within it as 2 rows:

I have 8 divs (class="item_css") within a div(class="example_box"), how do I display the 8 items in 2 rows, so it shows a row of 4 and then another 4.
I want to avoid using the 'rows' class. What would be the best way to do this?

**CSS**

```
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .body_background {
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        
        .example_banner {
            background-color: rgb(247, 245, 245);
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 3% auto;
            padding: 4% 0%;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #cccccc;
        }
        
        .example_banner_label {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 2px auto 25px;
        }
        
        .example_banner_heading {
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0% auto;
            color: rgb(7 29 148);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px #c7c7c7;
        }
        
        .example_banner_box {
            width: 90%;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0% auto;
            padding: 0%;
        }
        
        .example_banner_frame {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            height: auto;
            width: 1200px;
            margin: 0% auto;
            padding: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
        }
        
        .example_banner_frame_maincontents {
            width: 300px;
            height: 450px;
        }
        
        div.example_consumer_banner {
            width: 300px;
            height: 60px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 0%;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            background-color: #193cad;
        }
        
        .example_consumer_img_label {
            width: 20%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 10%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            color: rgb(255 255 255);
            text-decoration: none;
            text-shadow: -3px 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0);
        }
        
        .example_box {
            width: 75%;
            height: 450px;
            background-color: #00b6f3;
        }
        
        .item_css {
            width: 25%;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 0%;
            padding: 3px;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
  <section class="main_body">
        <div class="body_background">
            <div class="row" id="merch_rows">
                <div class="example_banner">
                    <div class="example_banner_frame">
                        <div class="example_banner_frame_maincontents">
                            <div class="example_consumer_banner" for="">Lorem ipsum</div>
                            <img src="" class="example_consumer_picture">
                            <label class="example_consumer_img_label" for="example_consumer_picture">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="example_box">
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: red; border: 1px solid grey;">1
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: orange;border: 1px solid grey;">2
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: green;border: 1px solid grey;">3
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: yellow;border: 1px solid grey;">4
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: blue;border: 1px solid grey;">5
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: black;border: 1px solid grey;">6
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: grey;border: 1px solid grey;">7
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_css" style="color: pink;border: 1px solid grey;">8
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean column instead of a row?

Comment: You could accomplish this with [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple example on flexbox:

```
.example_box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item_css {
    width: 24%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

or grid:

```
.example_box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox would do this.

https://jsfiddle.net/za678wcL/

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}
```